# Why all statements don't replace?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace statements by this codes .
Here is my HTML codes :

```
<p id="mytxt" >**SC-start**<br/>This is a code<br/>**SC-end**</p>
<p id="mytxt" >**SC-start**<br/>This is a code<br/>**SC-end**</p>
<p id="mytxt" >**SC-start**<br/>This is a code<br/>**SC-end**</p>

<button onclick="replacewords()" >Show This</button>
```

and here is my Javascript codes :

```
function replacewords() { 
    var curs = document.querySelectorAll("#mytxt");

    for (var i = 0 ; i <= curs.length ; i++ ) {
    var str = curs[i].innerHTML;
    var str0 = str.replace("**SC-start**" , "<pre>");
    var str1 = str0.replace("<br>" , "");
    var endstr = str1.replace("**SC-end**" , "</pre>");
    document.getElementById("mytxt").innerHTML = endstr ; 
}
}
```

Comment: replace `document.getElementById("mytxt").innerHTML = ...` with `curs[i].innerHTML = ...` - although the now deleted comment about unique ID's is correct, querySelectorAll **will** get all 3 `<p>` with the same id - your only mistake is reading the value using the querySelectorAll element and writing it using getElementById

Comment: Not sure why the comment was deleted, but, really, ID's need to be unique in a HTML document. Although `querySelectorAll` works for you, I would highly recommend using classes for "grouping" similar elements together

Answer (score 0):

replace the `id` in each `p` with `class`, because id is only for unique elements while class can represent multiple elements. Then, put this in your code:

```js
function replacewords() {
    var mytxt = document.getElementsByClassName("mytxt");
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= mytxt.length ; i++ ) {
        var str = mytxt[i].innerHTML;
        var str0 = str.replace("**SC-start**" , "<pre>");
        var str1 = str0.replace("<br>" , "");
        var endstr = str1.replace("**SC-end**" , "</pre>");
        mytxt[i].innerHTML = endstr; 
    }
}
```

```html
<p class="mytxt" >**SC-start**<br/>This is a code<br/>**SC-end**</p>
<p class="mytxt" >**SC-start**<br/>This is a code<br/>**SC-end**</p>
<p class="mytxt" >**SC-start**<br/>This is a code<br/>**SC-end**</p>

<button onclick="replacewords()" >Show This</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First replace in your html the id property for class.
Then, in your javascript use curs[i].innerHTML

```
function replacewords() { 
  var curs = document.querySelectorAll(".mytxt");
  for (var i = 0 ; i <= curs.length ; i++ ) {
    var str = curs[i].innerHTML;
    var str0 = str.replace("**SC-start**" , "<pre>");
    var str1 = str0.replace("<br>" , "");
    var endstr = str1.replace("**SC-end**" , "</pre>");
    curs[i].innerHTML = endstr ; 
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/sobasugovu/edit?js